# How can I create a matrix , with random number on row and not replace,but in col can replace, R language

Tags: r

How can I create a matrix , with random number on row and not replace.
like this

```
 5 29 24 20 31 33    
 2 18 35  4 11 21    
30 40 22 14  2 28  
33 14  4 18  5 10   
10 33 15  2 28 18    
 7 22  9 25 31 20    
12 29 31 22 37 26   
 7 31 34 28 19 23   
 7 34 11  6 31 28
```

my code :

```
matrix(sample(1:42, 60, replace = FALSE), ncol = 6)
```

But I receive this error message:

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :    cannot take a
>   sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

but it's wrong because only 1~42, it can't create a 60 matrix.

Comment: Do it per row?
`t(sapply(1:10, function(x) sample(1:42, 6, replace = FALSE)))`

Comment: can use replicate maybe: `matrix(replicate(2, sample(1:42, replace = FALSE)), ncol=6, nrow=10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not generate all 60 of the numbers with one sample function as you want to allow replacement of numbers in a different row. Therefore you have to do one sample per row. @Jav provided very neat code to accomplish this in the comment to the question:

```
t(sapply(1:10, function(x) sample(1:42, 6, replace = FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have a different sample in each row, then `replicate` can help you -- but `replicate` (as pretty much everything else in R) works naturally columnwise, so you have to transpose the result:

```
t(replicate(10, sample(1:42, 6)))
```

- `replace = FALSE` is the default, so I didn't include it
- after transposing, `10` becomes the number of rows and `6` becomes the number of columns